# .htaccess deny access multiple files

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I would like to deny access to multiple files with exactly name. So I tried with no success:

```
<Files config.inc.php config_smtp.inc.php>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

I cannot use FilesMatch because I want to deny files with exactly name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot use FilesMatch because I want to deny files with exactly name.

`FilesMatch` is precisely what you can use. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "^(config\.inc\.php|config_smtp\.inc\.php)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

In this case the regex could be shortened a bit, eg. `^config(_smtp)?\.inc\.php$` to match the same two files as above.

Note that since you're on Apache 2.4, you should be using [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html) instead. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "^(config\.inc\.php|config_smtp\.inc\.php)$">
  Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```